# Problem in wien bridge oscillator

Tags: oscillator, wien-bridge

I have put up a circuit for Wien bridge oscillator using 741 op amp, with R= 390 ohm and C = 2.2nF, for operation around 200 khz ( gain is 4). However, it did not work so I switched the resistor in parallel branch with potentiometer. This is the closest I could get.

[image]

Here is the circuit, with Rf = 8.2K and Rs = 2.2K

[image]

Any change in potentiometer does not yield any output.

Can someone please tell me some way to improve this to get good sine wave ?

Comment: Schematic is needed.

Comment: Its a normal wien bridge oscillator; i thought people might be knowing the circuit of it.

Comment: What does your power supply look like?

Comment: 12 volts ( using a 12V-1A adapter, thats all I got). Negative supply using 7912 regulator.

Comment: Your power supply sounds fishy.  Please show your power supply schematic.

Comment: @markrages . I think there is a confusion over the regulator. I thought 7912 regulator converts the polarity; if you plug in +12V, it gives an output of -12 V, which now I doubt is not the case. Can you clarify this ? Also if that is the case, then to supply negative supply  to 741, do I connect ground to terminal 4 ( neg Vcc) and +12V to ground ? ( This confusion arose because until now in labs, we had worked on the breadboard kit, which already had negative supply included).

Comment: The 7912 does not convert positive to negative.  You need less than -15 V input to 7912 to get -12 V output.

Comment: Yes, if you have another supply, and it is floating, you can connect positive to ground and negative for -12 V power.

Comment: Why are using a museum op-amp?  Modern ones are a lot easier to power.

Comment: @markrages . I dont know what a floating supply is. But I am taking all my power supply through a power wall socket( using a multiplug and adapter as mentioned before). Can I connect, for the negative supply, one of the adapter's ground to -Vcc and positive to ground ? And yes, if this works with 741, i'll switch to LM358 for future projects; it just needs a single supply.

Comment: It should work.  You should measure 24 V from negative to positive supply terminals of the op-amp.

Comment: @markrages and EM Fields. Thanks to both of you( Markrages for getting supply issue sorted). I do get a sinewave now. On the advice of Em Fields, i decided to wire the potentiometer in the feedback gain resistor instead of the parallel branch and adjusted the gain, giving me a good sinewave.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the 741, which doesn't have enough gain at 200kHz to overcome the loss of the bandpass filter.

Here's a schematic of the identical circuit with a decent opamp, which works, and the LTspice circuit list is [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ko2zrq8rvu6jqe2/Wien.asc?dl=0) if you want to play with the circuit.

[image]

Comment: The gain of the wien bridge oscillator should be greater than 3. That's what I have provided. So how does gain come into the picture here ?

Comment: It appears that your 741 has a gain-bandwidth product of less than 600kHz (a gain of 3 times a frequency of 200kHz) so no matter what resistance ratio you provide with Rf/Rs, the opamp itself is inherently incapable of providing that gain.

Comment: Infact, following your advice, I decided to vary the gain as mentioned in comments above, giving me a good sinewave. Thanks

Comment: @plutoniumsmuggler: I doubt if you will succeed. A 741 type opamp never can be used for a 200kHz oscillator (due to its small-signal as well as large-signal limitations). If you select another amplifier watch the slew rate!.

Comment: @LvW . I am getting a 150 khz now using 220 ohms and 2.2 nF. So around 200 khz should be easy by using lesser value resistor.

Comment: 150 kHz using a 741 type opamp? OK - sinusoidal or triangle? I suppose - the latter, correct? No surprise.

Comment: @LvW . Well, it looks kind of sine ( i'd say around 90% sine, just its tops are not exactly round, but its definitely not triangle. And it fluctuates every 3 sec or so ). I assume this because I am using a 10K potentiometer and I need to adjust it very carefully to get the wave.( I ll be happy to upload a 5 or 10 sec clip if you say, and give a link)

Comment: @Plutonium smuggler, it would be interesting to know the difference between the calculated and the actual frequency of your output signal.

Comment: @LvW We had been taught the frequency of Wien Bridge follows the relation 1/( 2 * 3.14 *RC), 3.14 for PI ( and that's what wikipedia says as well). However I have seen some resources claiming the formula 1/ ( 2 * PI * RC *√6) . I am finding the second one more kindof realistic. By the first one, it's around 330 khz, by the second it's 135 khz. I am getting around 145 Khz.

Answer (score 1):

To Plutonium Smuggler: I think, it is more appropriate to respond to your last comment in this way.

1.) Undoubtly, the nominal frequency for the Wien oscillator is **fo=1/(2*Pi*RC)**. The other "resources" resp. formula you have found will, certainly, belong to another type of oscillator circuit.

2.) The above formula for the Wien type assumes an amplifier having a gain of "3" (without any parasitic phase shift). However, this cannot be provided by a 741 type opamp at a frequency of 200kHz.

3.) Does this mean, that this opamp cannot be used for oscillating circuits around 200kHz? No - it can be used. However, one must be aware of the consequences: It is not possible to DESIGN such an oscillator; it will be - more or less - a trial-and-error process because the opamp introduces additional phase shifts (which are not known with sufficient accuracy). More than that, these non-ideal opamp properties are different for the various opam types.

4.) Example: Using your values (220ohms and 2.2 nF) I have tried to produce oscillations (Spice simulation) for two different 741 types:

a.) µA741: 400mV at 135kHz for a gain of 1+3=4.

b.) AD741: 180mV at 142 kHz for a gain of 4.

5.) Evaluation: Of course, it was possible to create oscillations - however, at much lower frequencies as desired (335kHz) because the additional opamp phase shift must be compensated by a corresponding inverse phase shift of the Wien network. The required gain was found by trial and error.

6.) Question: Is it possible to derive the necessary gain values from the BODE diagram (loop gain ac simulation)? The answer is NO!. The reason is as follows: The oscillating circuit provides - as can be observed (400mV, 180mV) - automatic amplitude limitation caused by slew rate limitation. This is a non-linear effect (additional phase shift in the time domain) and cannot be seen in the ac simulation.

Comment: Thanks for this explanation. With reference to your point 4 and 5, it is not clear whether the simulations gave 135 Khz or 335 Khz. And you mean that I CAN increase the frequency, but only at the cost of amplitude ? That is in fact very good, because I can always feed it to a CE amplifier to get required amplitude. So now I am confused; what limits us or prevents us from using it for high frequency ? ( I thought it was Gain BW prod which limited this )

Comment: Actual value: 135 kHz (335 kHz was the target value using 220 ohms and 2.2nF); Yes - by trial and error method you can produce higher frequencies than expected for "classical" designs - but the result cannot be predicted and varies from opamp to opamp, and hardware will give other results than simulation. It`s no DESIGN - it is just "try-and-error".